# Receiving null point exception in the console for method even after having parameters in the method

Tags: selenium

> Getting error at this method

```
gettablevalueshopcart("//div[@id='Catalog']//tr",2,"Large Angelfish",0,"EST-1");
```

> Browser launching

```
    public class petstore {
public static WebDriver driver;
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\achelimi\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to("https://jpetstore.cfapps.io/catalog");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Sign In')]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Testing15");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("test@123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='SidebarContent']/a[contains(@href,'FISH')]/img")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Angelfish')]//preceding-sibling::td//a")).click();
        gettablevalueshopcart("//div[@id='Catalog']//tr",2,"Large Angelfish",0,"EST-1");
       // gettablevalueshopcart("//div[@id='Catalog']//tr",2,"",0,"");
        driver.quit();
    }
```

> created below method

```
public static void gettablevalueshopcart(String xPath1,int descriptionid, String expectvalue1, int itemid, String expectedvalue2) {
```

> Used try and catch ,able to see output as null

```
try
{
 //String xPath1 = "//div[@id='Catalog']//tr";
    List<WebElement> shoppingtableList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath1));
    System.out.println("Item ID\t\tProduct ID\t\tDescription\t\tInstock\t\tList Price\tTotalcost\t\tButton");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    for(int i=1;i<shoppingtableList.size();i++) {
        List<WebElement> listData = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath1+"["+(i+1)+"]/td"));
        for(int j=0;j<listData.size();j++) {

            System.out.print(listData.get(j).getText()+"\t\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    // description is in the 3rd(2nd index) column so we can fetch that with the index number 2.
    for(int i=1;i<shoppingtableList.size();i++) {
        List<WebElement> listData = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath1+"["+(i+1)+"]/td"));
```

> Compared expected output with actual value

```
       if(listData.get(descriptionid).getText().trim().equals(expectvalue1)) 
        {
            System.out.println("Description for Item ID is "+listData.get(descriptionid).getText());
        }
```

Compared expected output with actual value

```
     if(listData.get(itemid).getText().trim().equals(expectedvalue2)) {
                System.out.println("Item ID is  "+listData.get(itemid).getText());
            break;
            }
        }

}

catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
}
}
```

Comment: I have tested your code and it is working fine.

Comment: thank you its working fine:)

Comment: Nice to hear!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the entire code.Copy and paste it.I have declared `WebDriver` globally.

```
package SeleniumPractice;

import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
public class TestS_1 {
public static WebDriver driver;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\achelimi\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.navigate().to("https://jpetstore.cfapps.io/catalog");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Sign In')]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Testing15");
        driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("test@123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='SidebarContent']/a[contains(@href,'FISH')]/img")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Angelfish')]//preceding-sibling::td//a")).click();
        gettablevalueshopcart("//div[@id='Catalog']//tr",2,"Large Angelfish",0,"EST-1");
        driver.quit();

    }


public static void gettablevalueshopcart(String xPath1,int descriptionid, String expectvalue1, int itemid, String expectedvalue2)
    {
        try
        {
         //String xPath1 = "//div[@id='Catalog']//tr";
            List<WebElement> shoppingtableList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath1));
            System.out.println("Item ID\t\tProduct ID\t\tDescription\t\tInstock\t\tList Price\tTotalcost\t\tButton");
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            for(int i=1;i<shoppingtableList.size();i++) {
                List<WebElement> listData = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath1+"["+(i+1)+"]/td"));
                for(int j=0;j<listData.size();j++) {

                    System.out.print(listData.get(j).getText()+"\t\t");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }

            // description is in the 3rd(2nd index) column so we can fetch that with the index number 2.
            for(int i=1;i<shoppingtableList.size();i++) {
                List<WebElement> listData = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath1+"["+(i+1)+"]/td"));

                if((listData.get(descriptionid).getText()).trim().equals(expectvalue1)) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Description for Item ID is "+listData.get(descriptionid).getText());
                }
                if(listData.get(itemid).getText().trim().equals(expectedvalue2)) {
                    System.out.println("Item ID is  "+listData.get(itemid).getText());
                break;
                }
           }

         }
         catch(Exception e)
        {
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
}
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Item ID     Product ID      Description     Instock     List Price  Totalcost       Button
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
EST-1       FI-SW-01        Large Angelfish     $16.50      Add to Cart     
EST-2       FI-SW-01        Small Angelfish     $16.50      Add to Cart     
Description for Item ID is Large Angelfish
Item ID is  EST-1
```

Comment: its not working .you can add complete code in to your eclipse and tell me the solution .if you know.